# Deserialize WRAPPER_OBJECT key as property using Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm trying to deserialize this json data into list of objects:

```
[{
  "a": {
    "commonField": 1,
    "aField": "AAA"
  }
}, {
  "b": {
    "commonField": 2,
    "bField": "BBB"
  }
}]
```

Each object may be one of several types having both common and unique fields. Information about exact shape of an object is stored in json as key in the wrapper object.

I created corresponding classes for every known shape (set of unique fields) extending class containing all common fields. Also, I added Jackson annotations to the classes to enable polymorphic deserialization. Simplified, resulting classes look like this:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = Id.NAME, include = As.WRAPPER_OBJECT, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
  @JsonSubTypes.Type(KeyBasedSubTypeA.class),
  @JsonSubTypes.Type(KeyBasedSubTypeB.class)
})
public abstract class KeyBasedSuperType {
  public String type;
  public int commonField;
}

@JsonTypeName("a")
public class KeyBasedSubTypeA extends KeyBasedSuperType {
  public String aField;
}

@JsonTypeName("b")
public class KeyBasedSubTypeB extends KeyBasedSuperType {
  public String bField;
}
```

With this setup Jackson works *almost* perfectly. It is able to choose correct subtype during deserialization and populate all the fields including common and unique. However, the `type` field is not updated by Jackson, the key value used for selecting subtype is not stored anywhere. In other words, the data is deserialized into following structure:

```
[KeyBasedSubTypeA { type=null; commonField=1; aField=AAA },
 KeyBasedSubTypeB { type=null; commonField=2; bField=BBB }]
```

Note `type` field having null value. So, the question is - **How can I make Jackson to store wrapper's key used for selecting subtype somewhere in resulting object?**

Here is my JUnit test for the process

```
public class PolymorphicTest {
  private static ObjectMapper mapper;

  @BeforeClass
  public static void init() {
    mapper = new ObjectMapper();
  }

  @Test
  public void testKeyDenominator() throws IOException {
    TypeReference<List<KeyBasedSuperType>> dataShape =
        new TypeReference<List<KeyBasedSuperType>>() {};
    List<KeyBasedSuperType> result = mapper.readValue(
        PolymorphicTest.class.getResourceAsStream("polymorphic-key.json"), dataShape);
    assertEquals(2, result.size());
    assertEquals(KeyBasedSubTypeA.class, result.get(0).getClass());
    assertEquals(KeyBasedSubTypeB.class, result.get(1).getClass());
    assertEquals(1, result.get(0).commonField);
    assertEquals(2, result.get(1).commonField);
    assertEquals("a", result.get(0).type); // <---- this line fails
    assertEquals("b", result.get(1).type); // <---- this line fails
    assertEquals("AAA", ((KeyBasedSubTypeA) result.get(0)).aField);
    assertEquals("BBB", ((KeyBasedSubTypeB) result.get(1)).bField);
  }

}
```

Comment: `type` field is handled internally by `Jackson` and you should not have this property in your class. You can create `public abstract String getType()` method and implement in each class because you know the type anyway.

Comment: The behaviour you described is default, but can be changed with `visible=true` on `@JsonTypeInfo` annotation

Answer (score 4):

The solution actually was very close, just missed a tiny step forward. It is `@JsonTypeInfo(visible=true)` required to make Jackson handle type info as normal property.

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = Id.NAME, include = As.WRAPPER_OBJECT, property = "type", visible = true)
@JsonSubTypes({
  @JsonSubTypes.Type(KeyBasedSubTypeA.class),
  @JsonSubTypes.Type(KeyBasedSubTypeB.class)
})
public abstract class KeyBasedSuperType {
  public String type;
  public int commonField;
}
```